# Which safety concerns exists when using stdin in PHP?

Tags: php, security, stdin

The next code is enough to receive stdin data from third party software, and seems to have no input size limit:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q

<?php
    $fh_stdin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
?>
```

When there is a range of data to be expected (independent of how wide or narrow), could restricting the input prevent excessive data to cause performance issues?

If so, how to prevent it?

Comment: yes, there is an input size limit: php's `memory_limit`.

Comment: Ok, there is a memory limit, but why use it all needlessly or process huge data that probably hasn't any use?

Comment: http://php.net/fread   there's a second option to specify how much you want to read. so someone could through a terabyte at you, and you'd only read the (say) 1 byte you really wanted.

Comment: It's opened as a stream, so the actual amount of data read in to the process, its format, and how it's handled "safely" is entirely up to *you*.

Comment: If you expect lot of data, load and process it in chunks and don't load them at into memory (php variable).